# Trying to use a variable as Hyperlink markdown in Discord

Tags: c#, json, discord.net

actually Im working on an Upload-Bot for Discord. My problem is I wanna use a variable (that contains a api permalink) as a Hyperlink markdown.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

But it should look like this: (The "Vale Guardian" Hyperlink mardown should contain the permalink from the "DpsReportVg" variable)

[image]

```
using (WebClient client2 = new WebClient())
            {
                DpsReport1 = client2.DownloadString("https://dps.report/getUploads?json=1&userToken=5656165565161312564651635");
            }

            var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(DpsReport1);
            string DpsReportVg = dataObject.uploads[3].permalink.ToString();


            var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.WithTitle("DPS-Reports uploaded by ");
            embed.WithDescription(Context.User.Username);
            embed.WithColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
            embed.WithCurrentTimestamp();
            embed.AddField("Spirit Vale", "[Vale Guardian](DpsReportVg)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, but you're overlooking a minor detail. 
You have
`embed.AddField("Spirit Vale", "[Vale Guardian](DpsReportVg)");`

But what you should have is
`embed.AddField("Spirit Vale", $"[Vale Guardian]({DpsReportVg})");`

Explanation: 
You aren't actually using your variable, you are just adding a String that happens to match your variable name.
My edit to your code uses string interpolation to insert your variable into your string thereby providing the actual link that you have stored in the variable.

Comment: Unrelated, consider using a singleton instance of HttpClient instead of WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `EmbedBuilder.withUrl` method:

Check out the official docs for a complete example with images:

https://discord4j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Making-embedded-content-using-EmbedBuilder/

Comment: Ty but i tried this befor but if i use it the title wil get linked and not the object value in the field. thats what im  trying to do :).

Comment: Have you tried the same exact example as in the docs and did it produce the same results as in their screenshot? If not then I'm afraid the API has changed and docs needs an update.

Comment: Yeah i tried it like in the example and it woks like in the example. but if i write it like this ```embed.AddField("Spirit Vale", "[Vale Guardian](https://www.google.de/)");``` it works but in wanna change the https://www.google.de/ with my variable DpsReportVg.

Comment: I guess @Anu6is nailed it!